# "errorMessage": "time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'" in Lambda Script AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to put this format in the code.

**State transition reason : User initiated (2020-04-06 17:00:32 GMT)**

Code line:

```
transition_timestamp = datetime.strptime(instance['StateTransitionReason'][16:39], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

It throws me error

"errorType": "ValueError",

"errorMessage": "time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'"

As far as I see, the format is correct. Please assist on this.
Thank You.

Comment: What is the output of `instance['StateTransitionReason'][16:39]`?

Comment: Without knowing the value of `instance['StateTransitionReason'][16:39]` its hard to know how to progress this question

Comment: I have posted this in original post already.. again     State transition reason : User initiated (2020-04-06 17:00:32 GMT)

Comment: @Marcin State transition reason : User initiated (2020-04-06 17:00:32 GMT)

Comment: Can some one help on this plz